# Desktop Feed Reader which can sync with Google Reader

Tags: sync, notification, messaging-menu

I am looking for a **Desktop Feed Reader** which can sync with Google Reader and sits in the messaging menu and give desktop notifications. 
It should be like, when I have marked an item as 'read' on gReader then the Desktop feed reader should also know that the item has been read.

I have tried Liferea but it is not integrating into the messaging menu:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[liferea](http://packages.ubuntu.com/liferea) does all of the above.

```
sudo apt-get install liferea
```

Comment: Cant seem to find the google sync option in liferea and it doesn't integrate into the messaging menu for me. http://i.imgur.com/UnPNw.png

Comment: Select New Source from the Subscriptions menu, and select Google Reader.

Comment: It does integrate with the messaging menu. Perhaps you need to log off? http://imgur.com/XUN6z.png http://imgur.com/Osufa.png There is an option on the GUI tab of Liferea's preferences to start minimised to the messaging menu - there doesn't seem to be an option to not be there or not.